# Python: slow processing of million records

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to process a data ( contained in a disk file later loaded into `numpy.array` instance ) with rows like:

```
1 3 a
1 4 b
1 5 a
2 6 b
```

where the first column is a start time, second column is an end time and third column is an id. I want to process these data so as to identify a number of ids at each start time like:

```
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
5  2
6  1
```

where first column is a start time and second column is number of ids

I have written the following code to process it as:

```
j=[]                                          # a list of ids
for i in range( len( dataset1 ) ):
    indices = numpy.argwhere( ( dataset1[i,0] >= dataset[:,0] )
                            & ( dataset1[i,0] <= dataset[:,1] )
                              )
    j.append( len( set( dataset[indices[:,0],2] ) ) )
```

where:
- **`dataset1`** has first column as 1,2,3,4,5,6 timestamps, and
- **`dataset`** has three columns: start time, end time and id.

I have to process about 9 hundred million rows as given in `dataset1`. This is very slow.

I tried to parallelize it as:

```
inputs = range( len( dataset1 ) )

def processInput( b ):
    indices = numpy.argwhere( ( b >= dataset[:,0] )
                            & ( b <= dataset[:,1] )
                              )
    return( len( set( dataset[indices[:,0],2] ) ) )

num_cores = 10

results = Parallel( n_jobs = num_cores )( delayed( processInput )( dataset[j,0] ) for j in inputs )
```

But this is still slow. I have 10 more cores available but then disk becomes bottleneck.

Is there any way to process this data fast?

Comment: `id a` and `id b` are both on at `time 1` surely? So the first line of output should be `1 2` shouldn't it?

Comment: Are the times all integer? Are the data sorted? If so, how? What's the highest time likely to be - any idea?

Comment: maybe you should try parse it in plain python and not `numpy`, because your solution is at least O((2n)^2) because you go over the array in the `for` once and in the `argwhere` twice. You should take advantage of the fact that the array is sorted, or sort it and parse it with one go

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes I will correct the first line. Yes the time is given as timestamp in seconds.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Highest timestamp is 1869900

Comment: Do the timestamps start at 0? If not, what's the likely lowest?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Lowest is 600

Comment: Why have you suddenly got 2 datasets now? And what is a *"first column as 1,2,3,4,5,6 timestamps"*? I make that 6 columns...

Comment: @MarkSetchell There is only one dataset. The set I have given above is an example set not the actual dataset. I have given it for the case of simplicity in understanding.

Comment: @KárolySzabó Are you mentioning like this: for i in range(len(dataset1):
    d1=dataset[dataset[:,0]<=dataset1[i,0],:]
    j.append(len(set(d1[d1[:,1]>=dataset1[i,0],2])))
This is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *Is there any way to process this data **fast**?*

Yes, there is.

<sub>( Python ***threads*** do not help here a bit, due to GIL-locking (re-serialising all efforts in a pure-`[SERIAL]` sequential processing, with add-on overheads for increased intensity of the hunt for the GIL-lock acquisition ), Python ***process***-based parallelism is expensive and replicates all RAM-data, including the itnerpreter as many times one asks ( disk blocks, because it swaps RAM, not because of smoothly reading down the lane but some **`< 1E9`** data-rows in a file, sure, unless you have multi-**[TB]** RAM-device to hold all python-process/data-copies at once ) )</sub>

---

### Step 1:
setup an efficient flow of DATA into a just-enough efficient processing

prepare data-file to best suite your further trivial counting of `id`-s

```
sort -k1,1       \
     -k3          \
     --parallel=19 \
     --output=dataset1_SORTED_DATA.txt < dataset1_data_file.txt

sort --parallel=19 \
     --output=dataset_SORTED_GATEs.txt < dataset_T1_T2_GATEs_data_file.txt
```

---

### Step 2:
sequentially process the sorted-file as per "gating" read from 2nd file

The first `dataset1_SORTED_DATA.txt` file next simply process ( count continuous, sequential blocks of rows matching the conditions ), reading it just once, sequentially, as dictated by using the also sorted `< T1_start, T2_end >`-gates, prepared in the second `dataset_SORTED_GATEs.txt` file.

This, almost a stream-processing, is smooth and uses just a plain counting of rows, that meet both the conditions from `...SORTED_GATEs.txt` data file, where `< T1, T2 >`-gates, that again monotonically grow larger and larger, so the first `...SORTED_DATA.txt` file gets processed in a one, smooth pass-through, counting just the `id`-s, as was requested.

Comment: Can you please provide a detailed walkthrough for the code. For example, I could guess using of first sort command in step 1 on dataset1. But dataset1 is already sorted. So what does sort -k1,1       \  -k3 exactly do?